# router redirect in express not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have 3 files
app
routes/index.js
routes/home.js

app.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();

//require routes
var index = require('./routes/index.js')
var home = require('./routes/home.js')


app.set('port',3000)
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/home' , home);



//app.use('/routes',users);
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/' , function(req,res){
    res.redirect('/home')   
})


module.exports = router;
```

home.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/home' , function(req ,res){
    res.send('Got request on home route')
})


module.exports = router;
```

This sends a cannot GET on HOME route.Strangely this works if i put both routes in one file.I think I am making a mistake while importing?

Comment: delete `/home` in `router.get` function in home.js file. so it becomes `router.get('/', ...)`.

Comment: This works!But i dont understand the working? there is no seperate route handler for Get on /home but it still works.Thanks